# Easiest way to implement minimize function using custom icon in JDialog

Tags: java, swing, jdialog, windowlistener

I want to implement minimize function for JDialog , using custom minimize graphic icon.
I have google it but not found any satisfactory solution.
I found some how close solution on 
[this page](http://www.javafaq.nu/java-bookpage-26-5.html)

but its for implementing JFrame , and i want to implement for JDialog.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably looking for a `WindowListener`:

```
JDialog f = new JDialog();
f.setSize(100, 100);
f.setVisible(true);

f.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {

   @Override
   public void windowIconified(WindowEvent e) {
      System.out.println("Hi!");
      // Do here your custom action
   }

});
```